# What is the deep link url to Google Pay / Wallet

Tags: deeplink, google-pay

There was another answer that stated `shoebox://` is the url for Apple Pay, so I'm wondering if there's an equally weird name for Google Pay which may be the reason why everything I've been trying isn't working.

Aside from the topic question, how does one find out that the url is `shoebox` anyways?!

Comment: Deep link for what?

Comment: Google Pay Send or Google Wallet. Whichever is available. If I don't find it I'm going to have to resort to rendering a WebView with the URL to the google pay website :(

Comment: Hi Friendly-Robot. You don't need to redirect the user to any website or application to checkout. You can add a pay button to your website or application using the Google Pay APIs (https://developers.google.com/pay/api/).

Answer (score 2):

I just find the scheme Uri for actual Google Pay app (2022) :

```
https://www.android.com/payapp/
```

The way to find it was to download apk of the app, open it with Android Studio and find scheme parameters in AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

https://gpay.app.goo.gl/kHXsJi (the 'Download for Android' link) from https://pay.google.com/about/) seems to work (Google Play is opened when Google Pay is not installed; the Google Pay is opened when installed). Note that this works for the new version of Google Pay (as of 2021).